# <Calculator.ViewController 0x7fe00b406090> setValue:forUndefinedKey ERROR

Tags: swift, xcode, class, swift3, xcode8

Anytime I try to run my project, the simulator only shows a white screen and then this appears on xcode:

[screenshotOfTheError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlLDg.png)

Comment: [More similare questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+setValue%3AforUndefinedKey)

Answer (score 0):

As it says in your error log, the label reference in the xib or storyboard exists, but you did it remove it from the class.

So just tap on `theLabel` in your xib file and remove outlet reference from it. And just in case, see if there are some leftovers of theLabel in your class.